# Problem with reducing the loss of a Neural Network

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network

I have a quite large data and a binary classification problem, which I want to train with neural network, I used more than 10 combination for my NN structure varying from 3 layers to 20, I also tried to over-fit my model on a smaller sample for the purpose of debugging, but my loss does not reduce at all!! It get stuck on 0.4 after number of epochs every times with every combinations and every sample sizes! But the strange thing is that the accuracy also does not reduce and it's around 0.8 which is not very bad!
As I'm new in working with NNs, any suggestion for solving the problem?
I use keras sequential model libraries.

here is my designed neural network:

```
#Normalizing the data
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
sc = StandardScaler()
X = sc.fit_transform(X)
print(X)

from keras import utils
y = utils.to_categorical(y)
print(y)

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train,X_test,y_train,y_test = train_test_split(X,y,test_size = 0.9)

#Dependencies
import keras
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
# Neural network
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(24, input_dim=25, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(22, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(20, activation='sigmoid'))
model.add(Dense(18, activation='selu'))
model.add(Dense(18, activation='sigmoid'))
model.add(Dense(16, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(16, activation='sigmoid'))
model.add(Dense(14, activation='tanh'))
model.add(Dense(12, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(10, activation='sigmoid'))
model.add(Dense(8, activation='sigmoid'))
model.add(Dense(8, activation='selu'))
model.add(Dense(7, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(5, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(4, activation='sigmoid'))
model.add(Dense(2, activation='sigmoid'))
model.add(Dense(2, activation='sigmoid'))

opt = keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.01)
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer = opt , metrics=['accuracy'])

history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=5000, batch_size=1000)
```

Comment: try adding some dropout layer. what other hyperparameters you played with?

Comment: try replace the the activation of the last layer from `sigmoid` to `softmax` and reduce the learning rate of `Adam` optimzer to 0.001. In addition try to use only `relu`activations, and please elaborate what exactly does your data contain...

Comment: @alivne yes, I used softmax as the activation of the last layer, but it didn't change much. my data contains 25 density features with different window function radius for 60000 particles. and the result should be information about the destiny of these particles, whether they will be in a halo or not, which makes an output array of 0 and 1 for each particle. I will try the "only relu" one. thanks.

Comment: @tausif I'll try dropout layers, thanks. I only played with learning rate and the structure of NN, I also tried some other loss functions, what other parameters can I play with?

Comment: Why don't you use fewer layers but with mcuh more neurons? In addition to adding everything that your colleagues have told you, it would be nice to use ```batch_normalization()```

Comment: @JorgeRodriguezSanJosé I use many layers in order to avoid rapid reducing of the number of neurons. I don't know if it's safe to do so :-??

Comment: Why are using sigmoid activations in the hidden layers? This will produce vanishing gradient problems.